# Windows 8.1 Resetting or Restoring

Tags: windows-8.1

I'm I going loose my **Original Operating System** from Resetting or Restoring the Dell Inspiron PC ?

I don't want to loose my OS but I'm ready to loose my personal data .

So what is the solution Please explain me regarding OS.

Comment: The solution for what?

Comment: Both options will reinstall the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

The integrated recovery option of Windows 8 resets the PC like if it was brand new.

This means a fresh new Windows installation and no datas.

You can check this : http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc

Answer (score 0):

Resetting your windows 8.1 Installation will only Delete the files. It will bring the OS back to its Original state meaning you dont have to reinstall windows it will act as a fresh install.

Answer (score -1):

usually no- its like a reset of your phone which will reset the OS to its base version, but still you should provide more details on how you want to reset your pc. Is there a software / tool / utility / CD ?

Answer (score -1):

Follow the link to reset your OS without loosing your Original Operating system. IF you have any question regarding this please don't hesitate to ask me

http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2302-reset-windows-8-a.html